# Form::Select from database model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table in a database (Candies) created from an Eloquent Model and I'm trying to generate a dropdown list using `Illumnate\html 'form::select'` with the values stored in the Candies table from the Candy_Flavor column.

I'm new to Laravel and after a few hours I was able to call the list in a regular unordered list, but I can't figure out how to pass in the values from the DB to the list. Am I missing something?

#### CandyController.php

```
class CandyController extends Controller
{
public function candy(candy $candy)
{
    $data = $candy->all();
    return view('pages.candy')->with('candies', $data);
}
```

}

#### Candy.blade.php

```
@extends ('master')
@section ('content')
    {!! Form::open() !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('name', 'Choose your flavor:') !!}
        {!! form::select('$candy->$candy_flavor') !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller use the lists function (assumes you have a 'name' and 'id' field)

```
$data = $candy->lists('name', 'id');
```

In your blade file use the following (edit it to suit your db column names)

```
{!! Form::select('id', $candies, Input::old('id')) !!}
```

Comment: No need for the call to `all()` before `lists()`.  That will add some extra processing that is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks @georgeQ! That was it, but i'm getting an error for 'Undefined variable: data' - i can see the array being spit out from the DB so I'll do a little bit more trouble shooting.